# Kanji use in these words, 今 vs 未

Tags: words, kanji

I'm learning vocabulary from 日本語総まとめN2. In one section they describe four words and group them together (I assume because they have slightly different meanings but somewhat similar). They group them with an example as follows:

> 今に　：　そんなことをしていると、今に後悔しますよ。
>
> 今にも：　今にも雨が降りそうだ。
>
> 今更　：　今さらできないといわれても困る。
>
> 未だに：　未だにその事件は解決していない。

I was wondering why 「未」 is used. Why not 「今」? Possibly I'm misunderstanding why this kanji is used because I don't know any other words with 「未」 that hold the pronunciation 「いま」.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think it can be either written as 未だに or 今だに, but probably the former is the official one. This is an example where the difference between ancient Japanese and Chinese is relevant. The Japanese native word いまだに comes from いま 'now', whose concept is written as 今 in Chinese, as you wrote, but Chinese had another concept 未 'not yet', which would better fit with いまだに, so the latter came to be written as 未だに.